# How do i create a file in the C drive using lua

Tags: lua

What I want to do is create a file that is pretty simple. But then I wanted to put it inside the C: drive but I am not really sure how...

this is what i currently have:

```
file = io.open("testFile.lua", "C:")
file:write("a semi-automated message")
file:close()
```

Comment: You can't just make up your own parameters. Read [the manual](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-io.open) and use the parameters it tells you to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to create a file in the C: drive, however, in order for the file to show up, you have to run the Lua file as an administrator via Command Prompt (or some other terminal)

```lua
file = io.open("C:\\main.txt", "a") -- appends a file named main.txt
file:write("Hello world!") -- write a bunch of stuff
io.close(file) -- close the file
```